# javax.mail is not sending mail to external domains in certain scenarios

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am using javax.mail API for sending the mails in a web application, where I am able to send the email to all domains.

In the same application, I am exposing a webservice which will accept the input data and send a email with an attachment. I am using the same code for sending the mails. **But, the email is sending only to the internal domain users(Ex: username@mydomain.com) .The email is not sent to external domains (Ex:username@gmail.com/username@yahoo.com)** .

Kindly help me if anybody knows what could be the reason.Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: It seems likely that the SMTP relay host is not allowing you to do this.  Are you using an internal relay host?  Is there block on sending emails with attachments?  That would be where I look.

Comment: Hi @stdunbar , Thanks for the reply. 
Yes, I am using an internal relay host. There is no block in the relay host for sending email with attachments. In fact, the web application also sends email with attachments.

Comment: Also I tried to send email without any attachment, still the mail is not delivered to external domains.

Comment: @stdunbar, Thanks , I have resolved this issue. As you said the SMTP relay host is restricting the email which are sent from invalid email(From Address) to an external domain. After using a valid from address, I am able to send email to external domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SMTP relay host  is restricting the email which are sent from email address with other domain names(From Address **Ex:uesrname@gmail.com / uesrname@yahoo.com**) to an external domain. After using a **valid from address(username@mydomain.com)**, I am able to send email to external domain as well.

Comment: But I am bewildered that why the SMTP relay host allowing email from invalid emails to the internal domain users.